# Proper Acceleration & Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

According to Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration), gravitation does not cause proper acceleration.
I’m having trouble understanding this. If we were an observer watching an object in free-fall at 10m/s/s, we could define that object’s velocity at any given moment. For any one of those velocities - or inertial frames - we choose, the object would still seem to be accelerating at 10m/s/s (assuming v << c). Is this not what it means to find the proper acceleration of an object?
I see people referring to proper acceleration as “acceleration felt by an accelerometer”. That seems like a different definition than “acceleration according to an observer momentarily at this rest with the object in question”. My intuition tells me - maybe incorrectly - that an object in a gravitational field would measure zero on an accelerometer because the accelerometer is experiencing the same non-zero proper acceleration as the object.
So, am I misunderstanding proper acceleration? Is the proper acceleration of an object in free-fall actually zero?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the Wikipedia statement. It's not enough that the observer be at instantaneous rest relative to the body studied (and it's not that important either). The important point is that he is in free fall there, and proper acceleration of the body is as observed in his (freely falling) frame.

Comment: I don’t quite understand the concept of a “free-falling frame”. That seems fundamentally different than an inertial frame. If two observers we on opposite ends of a massive object, they will both accelerate towards that object. Those frames seem “invalid” because they will no longer get the correct results from their force/acceleration calculations.

Comment: If you're an observer on Earth, or in a hovering rocket ship, then you're the one feeling acceleration, not the body in free fall. In general relativity the free falling body is the inertial one. This does mean that inertial frames cannot be arbitrarily extended, because spacetime is curved

Comment: In general relativity "inertial frame" is only local inertial frame, that is only bodies close to the center of the frame will move freely. Distant objects can and will move with acceleration even in inertial frame, due to gravity not being uniform.